# how to pass class to class is it possible in c++?

Tags: c++, class

Is this possible this way or another way to pass class to another class as parameter?? The point is that I want to pass many variables (vectors,integers,strings) from one class to another at once so that it is possible to use all the variables. And is it possible?

```
class classA{
 public:
     int a;
     ClassA(){
        int a =11;
        int b =11;
        int c =11;
        int d =11;
      }
     void function(){ 
       a++;
       b++;
       c++;
       d++;
     }
};



 class classB{
 public:
     int x;
     ClassB(class class1){
        int x = 21;
      }
     void function1(){
       x= x+class1.a+class1.b+class1.c+class1.d;
     }
     void function2(){
       x= x+class1.a+class1.b+class1.c+class1.d;
     }
    void function3(){
       x= x+class1.a+class1.b+class1.c+class1.d;
     }
 };

int main{
  ClassA class1;
  ClassB class2;
  class1.function();
  class2.function1(&class1);
  class2.function2(&class1);
  class2.function3(&class1);
  return class2.x;
 }
```

Comment: You should get familiar with the concepts of passing arguments by value, by reference, and by pointer.

Comment: I'd suggest reading into object oriented programming in c++

Comment: Stop trying to learn C++ by trial and error, that really will not work. Learn it systematically from a good book instead.

Comment: I see :(, this problem has occurred, when I was forced to create many variables inside a class instead in the main function

Comment: Do you know that in C++ the identifiers case matters?  You cannot name the class `classB` and the constructor `ClassB`.  You'll get something uncompilable.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a class object like any other variable, however, you need to pay attention how:

1. Pass by value: `void func(A a);` That is the standard. For large object, this could mean significant overhead, for complex objects that contain pointers, it might fail (a copy of a pointer points to the same data, not to a copy). To be able to pass a variable, *it needs to have a copy operation defined*. For classes, that means you need to have a copy assignment - either the default, or you own. If there is none, you cannot pass by value - the compiler simple wouldn't know how to copy it.
2. By Reference: `void func(A& a);` this means that the function uses the *same* object as the caller, not a copy; any activities apply to the original object. It is faster, because no copying is needed, but the danger is that the function might do things to your object that you don't know about.
3. By Pointer:  `void func(A* a);` the function gets a pointer to the original object. Basically identical to 'by reference', just the access syntax inside the function is different.

You need to understand all three to pick the right one.

Answer (score 2):

Passing an instance of a class is just like passing any other variable. You can pass by value:

```
void function(classA c);

classA a;
function(a);
```

This passes a *copy* of `a` to `function`, any changes made to `c` in `function` will not be seen by the caller.

You can pass by reference or const reference:

```
void function1(classA& r);
void function2(const classA& r);

classA a;
function1(a);
function2(a);
```

if `function1` modifies `r`, the caller will see it (i.e. so will `function2` in this sequence).

or you can pass by pointer

```
void function1(classA* ptr);
void function2(const classA* ptr);

classA a;
function1(&a);
function2(&a);
```

A complete example based on your code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int a_, b_;
    A() : a_(11), b_(11) {}
    void function() { a_++; b_++; }
};

class B {
    int i_;
public:
    B() : i_(21) {}
    void function(const A& a) {
         i_ += a.a_ + a.b_;
    }
    int i() const { return i_; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.function();
    b.function(a);
    std::cout << b.i();
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/ksIVRK